# How do I set up my Facebook account in Pidgin?

Tags: pidgin, facebook

Can anyone provide me a walkthrough of how to set up Facebook on Pidgin?

Comment: This is a helpful tutorial: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/12527/easily-add-facebook-chat-to-pidgin/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need facebook username to use with pidgin as well as empathy. Select protocol to facebook in pidgin add account

[image]

On username section enter just username i.e. facebook.com/USERNAME will take you to your facebook public page. If you don't have one you should get it.

Comment: sorry Sagar...but this doesnt work at all. I enter what you've asked me to enter and it says: Invalid XMPP ID. Username portion must be set.

Comment: I've tried almost all options and used this guide (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pidgin#Facebook_XMPP) to set up Pidgin for my facebook acccount, but it is simply impossible. At the username section I am using my actual username....not the long copied link from facebook...so that cannot be the issue. Is there anyone out there who had had issues of the same type?

Comment: I hope you are clear about `username` its not the `username` of your email that you use to login to facebook. Facebook itself provides username in its account settings sections. That is the `username` you should use. I am still focusing on this because I am using facebook chat with pidgin as I type this. Also check if there are certificates from facebook in tools > certificates section and try to remove it and re-try to login to facebook.

Comment: I had to change the port from 5222 to 443. Found that somewhere googling.

Comment: I had to restart the application. Now it is working just fine. Thanks guys.

Comment: Check the new settings at:
https://www.facebook.com/sitetour/chat.php

(Use Resource 'Pidgin' for example AND change the File transfer proxies (under Advanced tab) to: chat.facebook.com

You can indeed use port 443, somehow this works. Which is very nice if you are behind a firewall.

Answer (score 3):

Facebook has stopped this service for more see: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2015/04/facebook-chat-api-empathy-pidgin-stop-working

For those of you who want to use Facebook Chat in Pidgin, there's a new plugin which makes this possible, called purple-facebook
For more information see this: http://www.webupd8.org/2015/08/use-facebook-chat-in-pidgin-with-purple.html

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm this also, I went to my facebook page and went into General account settings and found the user name that facebook assigns. It is the long line with the http:// the only thing you need is the part where it has your name in it towards the end. I copy and pasted that into the part in pidgin where it ask for the user name and applied. Whola working pidgin that shows facebook im contacts. Hope this helps someone... Peace....

Answer (score 1):

Adapted from @vasandharaj's link, to be persisted here, because it simply works, although [FB announced the end of xmpp support by 30th of April 2015 (pidgin-im.de, german)](http://wiki.pidgin-im.de/doku.php?id=protokolle:facebook) and now it's the 6th of May 2015 and I connected right now for the first time.

### Setup Facebook Chat in Pidgin (using Jabber/XMPP)

### 1. In Pidgin go to "Accounts" and select "Manage Accounts". On the Basic tab enter the following info:

[image: Pidgin IM - Add Facebook account - basic settings]

- Protocol: XMPP
- Username: [your Facebook username, check your account setting for your profile URL]
- Domain: chat.facebook.com
- Resource: Pidgin
- Password: [your Facebook password]
- Local alias: [your name]

### 2. Click the Advanced tab, enter the following info:

[image: Pidgin IM - Add Facebook account - basic settings]

- Connection Security: encrypt connection if available.
- Connect port: 5222
- Connect server: chat.facebook.com

Ok, that's it. You can chat with your friends with Pidgin-IM.

Comment: I want to update that now it seems FB shut down the chat for external clients. At least I can no more connect with pidgin or jitsi.

Answer (score -2):

See the following link for instructions:

- https://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=371950911048

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I see your answer is not much more than a (non-functional) link. As this demonstrates, answers which consist of just a link are not useful if the link doesn't work. Please summarize the steps in your source back into your answer to help fight [link rot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot). Thanks!

Comment: Still not great but at least the link works now.